# Java Double and Float math behaving unexpectedly

Tags: java, math

I am getting a really strange output for what should be a really simple calculation. I'm trying to move a camera smoothly based on delta. If you look at CameraMenuAnimation() below, xMove and cameraDT are multiplied and added to cameraPosX. cameraPosX then spits out 1.7832639E11. This makes no sense?? CameraPosY does the same thing.

```
private double currentCameraTime, oldCameraTime, cameraFrameTime, cameraDT;
float cameraPosX  = 1.0f;
float cameraPosY = 1.0f;
xMove = .125f;
yMove = .125f;

private void CameraMenuAnimation(){
            cameraPosX += (xMove * cameraDT);
            cameraPosY += (yMove * cameraDT);
            GameCamera.setCameraPos(cameraPosX, cameraPosY);
            System.out.println("xMove: " + xMove + " cameraDT: " + cameraDT + " cameraPosX: "+ cameraPosX);
        }


    @Override
        public void update() {

        //some accumulator variables up here that I removed
            while (accumulator >= step) {
                currentCameraTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                cameraFrameTime = currentCameraTime - oldCameraTime;
                cameraDT =  cameraFrameTime;
                CameraMenuAnimation();
                oldCameraTime = currentCameraTime;
                accumulator -= step;
            }
```

It print out this from the println statement above. It makes no sense at all.

> System.out(8714): xMove: 0.125 cameraDT: 31.0 cameraPosX: 1.7832639E11

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: It would really help if you could provide a short but *complete* example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: have you checked cameraPosX before adding xMove * cameraDT?

Comment: It's too large. Wrong or missing initialization, perhaps of oldCameraTime? This would be the typical source for random strange values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say because you haven't given a complete example, but it looks like oldCameraTime is not initialized, so the very first cameraDT may be very large.

Comment: But when he prints cameraDT, it says it's 31.

Comment: That's why it's 'hard to say'. He does this is a loop, so I'm guessing we're seeing that last print, not the first.