# Simple java math function not working

Tags: java, math

This is driving me crazy and makes absolutely no sense.

```
private double currentTime, oldTime;
float dt;
float xMove = .125f; 
float yMove = .125f;
float cameraPosX = 1.0f;
float cameraPosY = 1.0f;


private void CameraMenuAnimation(){
    cameraPosX += xMove * dt;
    cameraPosY += yMove * dt;
    GameCamera.setCameraPos(cameraPosX, cameraPosY);
    System.out.println("xMove: " + xMove + " cameraDT: " + dt + " cameraPosX: "+ cameraPosX);
}

@Override
public void update() {
    currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    dt = (float) (currentTime - oldTime);
    oldTime = currentTime;

    CameraMenuAnimation();
}
```

In the println statement above it prints

> System.out(21557): xMove: 0.125 cameraDT: 20.0 cameraPosX:
>   1.7832686E11

This prints in a loop and cameraDT: changes value for each loop as it should. cameraPosX never changes value and the value is way too high. How can this be possible? It's just a simple multiply and addition statement in CameraMenuAnimation().

Also if I hard code the value of dt in it works.

```
private void CameraMenuAnimation(){
        cameraPosX += xMove * 20.0;
        cameraPosY += yMove * 20.0;
.../
```

How can this be possible?

Comment: Maybe it is chaning, but reaches a value too high too quickly, and then you can't see it going up anymore. Try to scale the movement down, like using `dt/1000` to see if that helps you catch the movement.

Comment: No because it goes it reverse once it hits a certain value. I didn't show that code. And like I said above if I hard code the value in it works.

Comment: Do you know what 1.78E11 means? Is that an acceptable cameraPosX for you? How did it get that high?

Comment: Do you initialize `oldTime` anywhere? Otherwise you will get a really large `dt` value the first time.

Comment: @Keppil You beat me to it. I suggest writing that as an answer, combined with the roundoff issues.

Comment: Douglas, no that's the point it makes no sense. It is a random number that doesn't change.

Comment: @Keppil that was it! Now I feel like an idiot. Please write it as an answer so I can give you the points.

Comment: It got that high because of the issue Keppil mentioned, that you don't initialize oldTime to be other than 0. Then it is so high that adding something small doesn't change it, since floats have limited precision.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Double and Float math behaving unexpectedly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105241/java-double-and-float-math-behaving-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you never initialize `oldTime`. This would explain the behavior you are seeing, that `cameraPosX` gets a really big value the first time around and then barely changes.

Answer (score 1):

You may check the assign value of this

```
dt = (float) (currentTime - oldTime);
```

i think this cause the problem.